# Should the operations of an operation-based CRDT be commutative?

Tags: crdt

I read Mark Shapiro's article on CRDTs but it is not clear for me whether all the operations of operation-based CRDTs should be commutative or not.

> For any two operations f, g in C(xi): (1) if they are not causally
> related then they are concurrent under <d (that is never stronger than
> causality) and must commute; (2) if they are causally related a → b
> but are not ordered in delivery order <d they must also commute; (3)
> if they are causaly related a → b and delivered in that order a <d b
> then they are applied in that same order everyware
>
> (*Shapiro et al., A comprehensive study of Convergent and Commutative Replicated Data Types, 2011, p. 11)*

It seems that causally related events that are delivered in that order could be non-commutative. In this case, this would allow a CRDT based on a defined data type operation with add and remove operations.

Assume a reliable broadcast channel and 3 replicas (A, B, C). A adds "a" to its set and broadcasts the operation to B and C. But due to network conditions, C receives the operation with high latency. Before C receives the operation, B already sends another operation to remove "a" from the set (see pic below). In the end, the three replicas do not converge, even though the events were broadcast in a causal order. So should the operations of an operation-based CRDT be commutative? Should operation-based CRDTs increase monotonically? Or is there something I don't understand?

[image]

Comment: Yes, they have to be commutative (hence the name Commutative Replicated Data Types). This can be sometimes a natural property of an operation itself - like in case of incrementing the Counters - but most of the time it needs to be guaranteed by the developer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct that only concurrent operations need to be commutative, *assuming* causal order delivery.

The issue in your example is that causal order delivery is violated: the `add(a)` message is causally prior to the `remove(a)` message, but replica C receives them in the opposite order.

> the events were broadcast in a causal order

What matters is the order of receipt, not broadcast. (Or in practice, the order of *processing*, since you can just delay processing a message that you received before its causal predecessors.)